# Javascript: Open 1+ links (that dont have content)

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, each, window.open

HI,
This makes no sense, but for example if i downloaded a file to your /Downloads folder and i wanted to run file:///.../Downloads/myfile1.txt i could just go:

```
window.location = "file:///.../Downloads/myfile1.txt;
```

But if i had say 10, or it was generated by a script.. how could i do effectively this.. open ...myfile1.txt => ...myfile1.txt
I tried running a jquery .Each() statement with an array of file names.. but it only opens the first one.

```
window.open();
```

That would leave me with hundreds of open windows, which i dont want :/

BTW. I'm not doing the file:/// but its not a http:// its local URL Scheme :)

Thanks!!

Comment: You're right, this makes no sense. What do you mean you want to "run a file"? What does it mean to "run" a `.txt` file anyway?

Comment: The question is unclear.  What is it that you want to do?  Do you want to open a series of local URL's, one after the other, in the current window?  Or... what?

Comment: Downloading hundreds of files this way is going to suck no matter what you do. How're your users going to manage the downloads? I suggest a slightly different approach - zip the files server-side, and make it a single download.

Comment: The default location for Downloads folder varies per OS and can be changed by the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're trying to do is open a series of URLs, one after another, in a single window, then I see a couple of options.

When you loop through the list, you could use window.open on each one, but give the window a name and use the same name for each -- that way it would open a single extra window and load each URL in it.  Note that it might well start loading one before the previous one has had time to finish loading, unless you add a pause of some kind, or use a callback approach.

The second approach is to load them, one after another, into an iframe on your page.  Same timing issues apply.

Comment: make an iframe for each window.open in a hidden div, then remove it before the next one is made :D

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to work because every decent browser will block access to local documents, downloaded or not.